# Cannot validate textboxes using jquery-steps plugin?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate, jquery-steps

I am using **jquery-steps plugin** in my project.Initially the tabs are working fine but when i wrote the validation script both tab and validation is not working.Is there any need to reference **jquery validator plugin** in my project.Any help would be appreciated.

The code i have used is given below

```
<head runat="server">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />  
<link href="css/jquery.steps.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.steps.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.steps.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<title></title>
</head>
<body>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#form1").steps({
        headerTag: "h2",
        bodyTag: "fieldset",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        onStepChanging: function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
             $("#form1").validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
             return $("#form1").valid();
        },
        onFinishing: function(event, currentIndex) {
            $("#form1").validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
            return $("#form1").valid();
        },
        onFinished: function(event, currentIndex) {
            alert("Submitted!");
        }
    }).validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            element.before(error);
        },
        rules: {
            confirm: {
                equalTo: "#password"
            }
        }
    });            

});
</script>
<form id="form1"  runat="server">          
            <h2>First Step</h2>
            <fieldset>
                  <legend> First Step Info </legend>  
                    <label for="userName">User name *</label>
                    <input id="userName" name="userName" type="text" class="required">
                    <label for="password">Password *</label>
                    <input id="password" name="password" type="text" class="required">
                    <label for="confirm">Confirm Password *</label>
                    <input id="confirm" name="confirm" type="text" class="required">
                    <p>(*) Mandatory</p>

            </fieldset>

            <h2>Second Step</h2>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Second Step Info</legend>   
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ut nulla nunc. Maecenas arcu sem, hendrerit a tempor quis, 
                    sagittis accumsan tellus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec a semper dui. Nunc eget quam libero. Nam at felis metus. 
                    Nam tellus dolor, tristique ac tempus nec, iaculis quis nisi.

            </fieldset>                                             
</form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic : Questions concerning problems with code you've written must _describe the specific problem_ — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.My guess was right.I need to reference jquery validator script into the project and now the validation works correctly.

My reference site was [jquery-steps](http://www.rafaelstaib.com/post/How-to-create-a-Form-Wizard-using-jQuery-Steps)